# Remover registro no banco de dados sem dar refresh

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Buenas! Procurei alguns tópicos sobre a mesma dúvida que a minha - e achei, porém não consegui entender como fazer... Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$c = array();
$c = buscaUsuario($conexao);

while($b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($c))
{?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $b["user_name"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $b["user_fullname"]?></td>
   <td><?php echo $b["user_email"]?></td>
   <td>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletarUsuario();"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
      </div>
   </td>
```

E quando clicar no botão de deletar ele vai chamar uma função js chamada deletarUsuario(), onde será passado o id daquele item em questão. Nessa função, é onde eu tenho que usar Ajax, mas não sei como fazer! Eu não sei como juntar a query de delete + javascript + ajax.

O motivo de eu querer fazer isso, é que ao clicar no botão de remover tal item, ele remova sem precisar que eu dê refresh na página.

Isto. Com a variável $b eu consigo recuperar o id, assim:

```
$b['id'];
```

Como eu não faço a mínima ideia de como usar Ajax, eu estava fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
   <a class="btn btn-danger" href="procura-cadastro.php?id=<?php echo   $b['id'] ?>">

    <?php
       if(array_key_exists("id", $_GET) && $_GET['id'] == $b['id'])
       {
                $a = $_GET['id'];
                $b = deletaUsuario($conexao, $a);
       }

        }
             ?>
```

Comment: Qual a url para excluir o usuário?

Comment: Esqueci de acrescentar, desculpe. Eu tenho uma página chamada deleta-item.php e nela, é onde eu coloco a query que deleta algum item.

Comment: Ele recebe por parâmetro o id pra ser excluir `deleta-item.php?id=1`?

Comment: Laerte, eu vou editar a minha pergunta com o trecho de código que coloquei aqui pra ficar melhor pra visualizar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai fazer assim:

```
$(".deletaUser").on('Click', deletarUsuario);

    function deletarUsuario(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        dados = {
            id : $(this).data('id')
        };

        $.ajax({
            url            : "deleta-item.php",
            type           : "POST",
            dataType       : 'JSON',
            data           : dados  
        }).done(function(data) {
          // aqui você faz alguma ação para quando o ajax retornar
        });
    }

<buttom class="deletaUser" data-id="<?php echo $b['id']; ?>">Deletar</buttom>
```

Ai é só receber o `$_POST['id']` no arquivo `deleta-item.php` e executar a query lá

EDIT:

Modifiquei a forma de chamar a função, tira o `<a>` que atualmente chama ela e coloca o botão que citei ali, ai muda o JS também.

Comment: Fiz a implementação como você me passou, porém ao clicar no botão nada acontece.

Comment: o jquery está configurado? da algum erro no console? o caminho pro arquivo deleta-item.php está correto (é ótimo colocar o caminho inteiro pro arquivo "http://...")

Comment: Agora que vi... No console está acusando que não está achando o arquivo que criei, ajax.js

Comment: testa ai e me avisa qualquer coisa

Comment: Pra testar, coloquei a função que você me passou dentro do meu código html (dentro das devidas tags é óbvio) mas no console acusa que a função deletarUsuario não está definida =/

Comment: rodei um teste aqui e a função funcionou normal, joguei ela no .js de um projeto que estou trabalhando agora e rodei a função pelo console do chrome, ela tentou achar o arquivo e enviou o id, até ai, o js está perfeito

Comment: "ReferenceError: deletarUsuario is not defined" :\

Comment: revisa pra ver se você está realmente incluindo o js no final do arquivo, tudo certinho, porque tenho certeza que ta funcionando

Comment: Uma pergunta bem idiota, mas no botão eu coloco:
<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletarUsuario($b['id'])"></a> ?

Comment: isso, você chama a função no onclick, só corrige pro php dar um echo na $b['id'] dentro da função, vai ficar assim: onclick="deletarUsuario(<?php echo $b['id']; ?>)" eu errei ali na resposta

Comment: Daniel, funcionou! Mas funcionou da mesma forma que eu havia feito anteriormente sem Ajax... Eu tenho que dar um refresh na página pra aparecer que o item foi deletado e eu queria fazer sem refresh...

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta, ele estava fazendo isso porque o navegado estava seguindo a função do botão (você estava usando um `<a>` certo?)

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined... (pra mim que o jquery estava incluso...)

Comment: as ordens de inclusão dos js estão corretas?

Comment: E quais seriam as ordens de inclusão? t-t

Comment: primeiro inclui o jquery, depois qualquer outro js

Comment: O Jquery já está incluso por primeiro...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Adicione a biblioteca jQuery no head do seu documento caso não esteja utilizando. Você pode baixar [aqui](https://jquery.com/download/) .

Na tr de sua tabela, coloque um **id único** que será utilizado para ocultar a tr após excluir. Observe que no link de excluir adicionei um **data-id** que será utilizado no javascript para especificar o usuário que deve ser excluido e uma classe **deletar**. Caso você queira utilizar o onclick você terá que passar como parâmetro o id do usuário.

**HTML**

```
<tr id="tr_<?php echo $b["id"]; ?>">
   <td><?php echo $b["user_name"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $b["user_fullname"]?></td>
   <td><?php echo $b["user_email"]?></td>
   <td>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger deletar" data-id="<?php echo $b["id"]; ?>"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
      </div>
   </td>
```

No código que faz o processo de exclusão pelo PHP 
retorne `[error => false]` caso o usuário seja excluido com sucesso ou `['error' => 'Mensagem informando alguma inconformidade']` que será capturado no success do ajax.

**JS**

```
function deletarUsuario(id_usuario)
{
      $.ajax({
         url: 'sua url para excluir',
          type: 'post',
          data:{
           id: id_usuario
         },
         success: function(response)
         {
              if (!response.error) {

                $('#tr_'+id_usuario).fadeOut('slow');
              } else {
                alert(response.error);
              }
         },
         error: function(xhr)
         {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
         }
      });
}

$(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.deletar',function(){
        deletarUsuario($(this).data('id'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Vale ressaltar que esse foi apenas um exemplo básico de implementação. Meu código pode ser melhorado.

Comment: Oi Miguel, obrigado pela resposta. Implementei seu código porém ele não faz acontecer nada - claro por provavelmente erro meu. No console também não aparece nada. Parece que a o código da função não está nem executando

Comment: @CesarA.Fonseca Você faz o carregamento da página via javascript ou PHP? caso utilize via javascript. você terá que mudar  $('.deletar').click  para $(document).on('click','.deletar',function(){}). verifique na opção Network + xhr do console para ver se o ajax foi executado

Comment: Eu acho que vou desistir de tentar aprender e fazer isso... Não consigo de jeito nenhum. O seu código e o do colega Daniel executam sem erro, porém não é feito a exclusão... E a query está correta, pois antes eu conseguia excluir mas a exclusão só aparecia ao carregar a página...

Eu procurei tutoriais na internet mas não consegui entender nada de como usar Ajax... Parece coisa de outro mundo :(

Comment: Nunca use essa palavra desistir. Essa não é a opção. Caso queira aprender mais compre o livro http://novatec.com.br/livros/ajaxjquery/ ajax com jquery

Comment: Oi Miguel... Obrigado pelo apoio cara. Eu não posso e vou fazer de tudo pra não desistir. Por mais que JQuery, Ajax, pareçam coisas de outro mundo pra mim... Eu preciso aprender, preciso. Você poderia me explicar (ou melhor, me passar links) explicando o que algumas das tuas implementações ali fazem? Abri a documentação do Ajax mas não consegui entender muita coisa

Comment: Vou colocar na resposta

Comment: @CesarA.Fonseca  na resposta eu exemplifiquei passo a passo para você fazer a implementação. Se você está com dúvida na linguagem ai já é outro problema. Gostaria de poder ajudar. Mas agora depende de você.